# Array initialization needs curly braces

Tags: c, compilation, rot13

I have been trying to get this code to work to encrypt the `*char[]` pointer array with ROT13 encryption. Couple of problems:

1. The program does not compile. The Error is: 'text': array initialization needs curly braces.
2. ROT13 does not seem to be working properly. It saves the numeric value of the ASCII code rather than its equivalent letter.

Here is my code:

```
void rot13(int numlines, char * text[]){
    //printf("%s\n", text);
    //char encrypted[length(text)];

    for (int i=0; text[i]>='\0'; i++){
        if (*text[i]>='A' && *text[i]<='Z'){
            *text[i]=(((*text[i]-'A')+13)%26 + 'A');
        }else if(*text[i]>='a' && *text[i]<='z'){
            *text[i]=(((*text[i]-'a')+13)%26 + 'a');
        }
    }

    printf ("%d\n ",*text);
}

int main(){
    char text1[]="parliament";
    char * text[]=&text1;
    rot13(10, text);
}
```

Comment: So, did you try putting curly braces around this initialization? (The line it has problems with should be `char * text[]=&text2;`)

Comment: @dyp , what is `text2` ?

Comment: @CoolGuy A typo. It should be `text1`, of course.

Comment: The first parameter to `rot13` is called `numlines`, and the second parameter is an array of `char *`. This indicates that the `rot13` function is intended to handle multiple strings in a single call.  However, the body of the `rot13` function is written to only handle one string. So that's the first thing you have to decide. Does `rot13` handle multiple strings or just one string?

Answer (score 2):

In `char * text[]=&text1;`, `text` is declared as an array of pointers to `char`. Therefore is is of an array type. It can't be initialized without using curly braces (exception: string literals). Better to declare it as *pointer to pointer to char*

```
char **text = &text1;
```

You should note that the declaration `char * text[]` in `main` and in the function parameter is not same. When declared as a function parameter `char * text[]` is equivalent to `char **text`.